# Error in Loading a php page through JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I used this JQUERY code module for some purpose

```
$("#notice").show().load('update.php?first=1&institute='+sch+'&institute_code='+code,function(data,statusTxt,xhr) {
     $('#notice').show().html(data);}
    });
```

**update.php?first=1&institute='+sch+'&institute_code='+code** in the above code to be loaded
but its not working as it should work

On update.php I used this code

```
echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];exit;
```

and the output i got is

```
http://localhost/teach/index/update.php?first=1&institute=Delhi
```

While it should be

```
http://localhost/teach/index/update.php?first=1&institute=Delhi&institute_code=441
```

&institute_code=441 part is missing,
where am i making mistake? I know its a silly mistake but i am wasted of searching that mistake.

Comment: Just a guess: maybe sch value ("Delhi") is not just this literal exactly but contains a new line character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Pass JSON object it more clear.
2. Also as you are using `load()` you don't need to set data using `.html()`
3. Use `.show()` in the callback method only

Code

```
$("#notice").load('update.php', {
        'first': 1,
        'institute': sch,
        'institute_code': code
    }, function (data, statusTxt, xhr) {
        $('#notice').show();
    });
```

Comment: thanks but First line of this code is showing error [link of error image](http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-2422-273.html)

Comment: @AkashKumar, My bad missed a comma after `'update.php'`. Updated answer

Comment: Yes thanks, It worked very well with a minor change i.e. Delete the very last curly braces. Otherwise worked fine

Answer (score 0):

This is usually where I find the problem when data is posting properly also make sure you have the code association proper, to assign the correct database properly to the url bar.

/*Edit*/
Try this:

```
$("#notice").show().load('update.php?first=1&institute='+sch+'&institute_code='+code,function(data,statusTxt,xhr) {
     $('#notice').show().html(data);}
    );
```

/*Edit*/

Comment: Till time, no database connection part came into existence in my problem, its just JQuery part

Comment: I see now you are only telling the it to post data and not the the rest of the data. Are you sure you have all the spelling and syntax correct elsewhere.

Comment: Yes all spelling are correct actually error was in sending a string with white spaces in url but now, i send the data using POST